# Is it possible to have a working queue without a dedicated dyno in Heroku?

Tags: laravel, heroku

I have a Laravel 8 project hosted in Heroku with a "hobby" dyno. In this project I send emails via a queue.

To do that I have this procfile :

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/
worker: php artisan queue:restart && php artisan queue:work database --tries=3
```

If I have understood well, this profile generates two dynos: one for the web server and one for the queue.

For pricing reasons, I disabled the "worker" dyno.

[image]

And I tried to launch the command `php artisan queue:work` directly in the console. It works. Of course I must not forget to re-enter the command after each deployment!

Unfortunately, it works some hours only (sometimes it works for one hour, sometimes it works four hours).

My question are: Is there a way to make this queue work without this break? Are there any users here who do like me?

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
worker: php artisan queue:restart && php artisan queue:work database --tries=3
```

Instructs Heroku to start a Worker instance, which you can see in the dashboard as it asks you to enable it.

php artisan in the console only works for the lifetime of the session and can be used for debugging etc.

This is a way of cheating, I never tried it: https://crontogo.com/blog/how-to-run-php-laravel-scheduled-jobs-on-heroku/ maybe it wont work as Heroku Scheduler runs every 10 minutes minimum.

You could also mess around with the Procfile and do something like this:
https://gist.github.com/robbydooo/65bf341ea0f4081150b945bfb1d38d3c

Buuuut, it's not very scalable etc, Heroku is Paas, not IaaS so it's smart and great out of the box. It's very cheap anyway, even for small apps and for me personally I think it's worth to run the worker etc instead and it will work properly?

Hope you get it to work!